# Why my "webpack": "^5.70.0" is not able to process jpg file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, webpack, material-ui

I am trying to load a jpg file on the Homepage of my app:

```
import cad from './CAD/untitled.106.jpg'
```

but the following error kept popping up:

```
assets by status 2 MiB [cached] 1 asset
cached modules 2.41 MiB (javascript) 937 bytes (rjavascript modules 420 KiB
  ./src/components/HomePage.js 1.18 KiB [built]
  ./src/components/CAD/untitled.106.jpg 419 KiB [

(1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)       
 @ ./src/components/HomePage.js 7:0-41
 @ ./src/components/App.js 3:0-34 12:90-98       
 @ ./src/index.js 1:0-35

webpack 5.70.0 compiled with 1 error in 84 ms
```

I have tried modifying the webpack.config.js by adding a rule with 'file-loader'. However, the problem remained. Currently, I am using "webpack": "^5.70.0". Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./static/frontend"),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpeg|png|jpg|svg|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
            }
          }
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("development"),
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

I have tried many different approaches and solutions, and I have no idea why my webpack.config.js can not process a jpg file. Can someone tell me the root cause of this problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In webpack 5+ you can just load it as `asset/resource`

> asset/resource emits a separate file and exports the URL. Previously achievable by using file-loader.

So it should look like this:

```
{
    test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/i,
    type: 'asset/resource',
},
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error after including this in my webpack.config.js

Comment: Could you create a Minimap reproduction on codesandbox?

Comment: The problem was solved, your answer worked. It was a stupid mistake of my own, the only reason why I was still getting the same error after using the asset module was because I didn't restart my server.

Comment: awesome, was already curious. Please dont forget to upvote!